# How to return http Result in play framework in case of recovering future?

Tags: java, scala, http, playframework

in my controller im calling a method that returnes a future, and in my recover I want to return an http Result, so I did something like:\

```
myController = Action.async {

    myService.futureMethod().map(result => {
        Ok(result)
    }) recover {
        case exception =>
        println("futureMethod failed with: ",exception)
        BadRequest(exception)
    }

}
```

but i get this error:

> Cannot write an instance of Throwable to HTTP response. Try to define
>   a Writeable[Throwable] BadRequest(exception)

how can I make this right if i want to return http Result with the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BadRequest(exception.getMessage) should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the message from the exception, use the solution : BadRequest(exception.getMessage).

However, read up on the different types play (or http) in general can return and supports. Some types are : text, Json,XML.. this might help you have a better understanding.